# Xcode edit framework

Tags: ios, frameworks

I'm working in a project that has a framework someone wrote. I have access to the repo, and write permission.
I need to change something in a method, but not the signature.

Is it possible to do this in the .m file in the repo and it would get updated in the project? The framework is in BitBucket, so I should be able to edit it online there.

Edit
I'm working in Xcode 8

Comment: after edit method on the repo, you have to rebuild the framework

Comment: Do I have to create a new framework, or can it be rebuilt within the project that is using the framework?

Comment: have you used carthage? it download framework source code and compile it, you can do it manually, just compile new version of framework and replace file

Comment: The project uses Pods, but this is a private framework that was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlassian's BitBucket is essentially another version of GitHub (with slightly different features and implementations).

If this is a private framework that you have write access to, you should make sure that the framework's author/owner will allow you to merge your changes into his/her framework.  [Here's a tutorial on how to create a pull request in BitBucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/create-a-pull-request-774243413.html), and once it's merged, you can fetch the latest version of master to pull your change in.

If the private framework is actually [a private Cocoapod](https://objectpartners.com/2014/06/25/developing-private-in-house-libraries-with-cocoapods/), the podspec needs to be updated with a new version so your change will be picked up when doing a `pod update` on any machines that build your app and the private frameworks.

Comment: I have write permission to the repo, so I should be able to update it directly in the master branch. How does the project that uses the framework update it?